# How to browse a local disk directly using terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I am a beginner for Linux. I use *Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I am trying to browse into a local disk which is not in my home directory. It is not mounted in my Home directory. It is a separate partition.

How do I mount that partition into my media folder.

When I try to get into access directly without mounting, it shows

```
aravind@Aravind:~$ /media/aravind/Tech\ Stuff/os

bash:/media/aravind/Tech Stuff/os: No such file or directory
```

`Tech Stuff/` is a separate partition in my hard disk. What should I do to mount and access it?

I want to browse it through terminal or through a graphical browser as in Windows.

The command I typed might be wrong. So please suggest the right command.

Comment: What actually you are asking is to find a graphical directory browser, resembling more or less similar tools available on for example Windows? The answer is that there are plenty, but since your GNU/Linux distribution of choice is Ubuntu, try typing `nautilus` into your terminal.

Comment: Is the drive officially mounted?  And you might need quotes to deal with the "space" as in "/media/aravind/Tech Stuff/os" instead of /media/aravind/Tech Stuff/os.

Comment: can you, for starters, paste the output of the mount commando? 
The mount commando shows all the mounted partitions in the system. And can you also paste the output of following commando: 'ls -la /dev/'

Comment: I was just about to say: as others have said, the disk needs to be mounted first; but I also note that you haven't told the terminal prompt what you want to do with the directory you've written. To browse the contents of a directory use `ls /yourdirectory/etc...`. To traverse directories use `cd /yourdirectory/etc...`

Answer (score 1):

You can mount it like:

```
mount /path/to/your/partition "/media/aravind/Tech\ Stuff/os"
```

Just make sure the path `/media/aravind/Tech\ Stuff/os` exists, or create it with:

```
mkdir -P /media/aravind/Tech\ Stuff/os
```